# Grafana v7.0 cannot find Column Style option

Tags: grafana

As I use Grafana to get table from data source, however, since I upgrade version from 6 to 7 recently, I cannot find the option to change column style, some of my table columns are text then needed it to format it correctly. Does anyone know how to bring it back?

I attach 2 images of before and after I upgrade it.

[image: Before having column style]

[image: now it disapear :(]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Overrides` and override column options there:
[image]

Comment: I have tried override but this option does not allow me to format a column as text. Can you instruct me more detail?

Comment: @HàLink and how is text formatted? Just `column alignment: left`, what can be configured with `Overrides`. Job done.

Comment: Garaij Do you know the column style options, it has an option to set a column format as text. I have a column with hex string and it display as float numbers. I used can format it as text but now I cannot.